# Find ROM Size programmatically

Tags: java, android, rom

I am trying to create a test application for a device which checks the flash ROM size on the device for the tester to verify.

Is there any kind of function that Android Studio offers which can return the ROM size as a Long or Double?

Looking through Android documentation, so far I have only been able to get the RAM size as well as internal and external storage. Would I be able to retrieve the ROM size through Android Studio?